# How to convert char * to const OLECHAR * so as to be used in SYSALLOCSTRING()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please tell me how to use a string such as
char *xyz in SysAllocString() which takes OLECHAR const * as parameter

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how the `char*` is encoded you have some different options:

1. Is is what Windows refers as an ANSI-string, you could use the [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx).

   ```
   BSTR foo(const char* s) {
     return SysAllocString(CA2W(s)); // CA2W requires <atlconv.h>
   }
   ```

   or you could use `_bstr_t`:

   ```
   BSTR foo(const char* s) {
     return _bstr_t(s).Detach();
   }
   ```
2. Is it UTF-8, you could use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) instead.

Comment: Hi. In which file is CA2OLE defined?

Comment: @Hooch In atlconv.h, but it should have been CA2W. Updating answer now.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `char*` to `const OLECHAR*` you can use the macro [`A2COLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267943(v=vs.60).aspx)

So, if you have a 'char* pChar' it should be possible to do it like this:

```
const OLECHAR* pOleChar = A2COLE( pChar );
BSTR str = SysAllocString( pOleChar );
// do something with the 'str'
SysFreeString( str ); // need to cleanup the allocated BSTR
```

Answer (score 0):

this just as wchar_t so you can invoke function simply:
    SysAllocString(L"hello");
or if you have char* use mbstowcs_s to convert it to wchar_t.